# What does it mean when your invoice is immediately payable?

Tags: freelancing, billing, invoices

In the invoice, it says that the payment is divided into 2 stages:

1. Upon the start of the project: 50% is immediately payable.
2. After the end of the project: 50% is payable within 30 days.

What does it mean by immediately payable? Do I have to pay the invoice within 24 hours as it says "immediate"?

Comment: It likely means that you pay 50% up front (now), and the other 50% no more than 30 days after the project is completed. But really this is a question you should be asking the person who gave you the invoice, not us.

Comment: I agree with David you need to ask them, I wouldn't imagine they'll undertake much work if you don't pay 50% up front. Depending on the level of trust they may allow time for a payment to clear depending on the method.

Comment: Thank you David. I can understand that I have to pay 50% upfront. But, the one thing that bothers me is the word "immediate" as there's no specific term on how many days I should make the payment. I've emailed them, but haven't received any response yet. Is it possible that I can pay within 30 days too?

Comment: @jasap No, it means pay as soon as the invoice lands, before they will start working on the project. It usually exists to ensure any upfront costs are covered. You should have received payment details (bank info, etc) to make this payment.

Comment: @jasap no you dont have to pay it after 24 hours, but i couldnt tell you when it is due.

Comment: It's the "due" date, which means after 30 days you're 30 days in arrears. If something does come to non-payment, the clock is already running. You should pay soon, but there's nothing special about 24 hours.

Comment: @JohnHC Yes, I've received the payment details along with the invoice. I'm just worried that I might violate the terms and agreement if I pay late. For the goodness, I think I have to make payment within 24 hours. Thank you so much John.

Comment: "immediately payable upfront" basically means "Work will not start until that money is sent".

Comment: Thank you all, really appreciate your quick help on this matter. This community is indeed amazing!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an accounting question, not a workplace question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the payment is due now.  It could be that until the payment for the invoice is paid they will not start working on the project or it could be they are starting on the project and expect payment asap.  If you work for a company that has a process for getting checks cut that will take 3-5 days(or what ever your duration will be) I suspect if you let them know this that will be fine.  Just let them know they should receive the payment by a certian day.  If there is a problem with the time frame they should let you know

Answer (score 0):

It is different if they require you to pay before starting the project. What I would do is simply to call them to be sure about the delay you have. This depends highly of where you live. Could you give us more details about that ? In France at least I know that once you have received the invoice that says immediately payable, you have 30 days to pay for it.

What is sure is that they don't expect you to pay in the minute.

Comment: It varies by country. In the US, 'immediately payable' means that they want the money now, and most companies will get them paid within a week - quicker, if not paying means delaying any work. It sounds like you know the rules for France. In the UK. 'immediately payable' means any time between 30-days and three-six months hence (and is why I don't work too much with UK companies any more!)